# Mixing in connected gases

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, kinetic-theory, diffusion, gas

(This question is about the making of a box to enclose a 3D printer and its filament. 3D printer filaments are sensitive to ambient moisture. The model described below is only a simplification of the real design problem: how well sealed must be the box, where to place the door, use chemical or electric desiccant, etc).

Assume two cubic boxes of $1$ m$^{3}$ volume closed and placed over a flat surface, and that contacts only in one of its faces (that is, the boxes share one of its faces). The first box is filled with air that has a 80% moisture (water vapor in air), second one is filled with air at 30% moisture.

Assume a hole of 5 cm diameter is done in the face common to both boxes, connecting in this way their contents.

Will levels of moisture tend to balance, finishing in both boxes with the same percentage of water in air? How long time will this process take (main parameter of the curve if it is something like an exponential)? Has any effect the height of the hole (respective to the base surface)?

An exact formula isn't compulsory; approximative answers are also welcome. Also references to the physical laws or facts to be taken into account are welcome.

Note: THIS IS NOT HOMEWORK. Physics is useful outside schools.

Comment: -1. No research effort. What do you think? What difficulty are you having with this situation?

Comment: @sammygerbil: taken into account the answer received, it seems that the question has real difficulties to be solved by someone without the physics degree (and even by someones with it). I think there are lots of persons on stack exchange with happy trigger of down votes and close votes.

Comment: Having difficulty with the problem is not an excuse for not making an effort to answer it.

Comment: A new record in happy trigger of close-votes: classify as homework what is clearly stated as a real diy of one box for one concrete objective.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui "Homework-like" is not the same as "homework".  You're asking 2 quantitative questions without showing any research of your own.  The answers are only particularly useful to you; because you're asking for a _solution_ to a _specific_ problem; not an answer to a conceptual question.  This is also nowhere near a "record".  Questions like this commonly attract close votes.

Comment: @JMac: you think laws and facts about propagation of water in air is not "conceptual"?  only useful to me? finally, could you believe that someone without physics degree can have no idea of what is Fick's second law, even that it exists ?

Comment: @pasabaporaqui You didn't ask about the laws of propogation of water in air.  You asked for someone to _use_ those laws to solve a problem for you.  We are not a problem solving site.  I could definitely see someone with a physics degree not knowing a specific law.  Physics is broad; not everyone knows everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will levels of moisture tend to balance, finishing in both boxes with the same percentage of water in air?

Yes. As each water molecule has the same probability of eventually crossing the orifice from either box, as long there are more molecules in one of the boxes, there will be more of them, on average, crossing to the other. Eventually equilibrium (same humidity) will be reached.

> Has any effect the height of the hole (respective to the base surface)?

Unlikely, though that depends on what the printer is doing. For an empty box the influence of gravity on the process can probably be neglected.

> How long time will this process take?

For **diffusion driven** mixing, my rough estimate attempt (see below) is a half life **longer than a month**(!).

You should be able to obtain that from an expression like [Fick's second law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fick%27s_laws_of_diffusion#Fick.27s_second_law)

$$ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = D\nabla^2\phi, $$

where $\phi$ is the concentration of water vapor and $D$ the diffusion coefficient. I believe that you can take the size of the orifice into account by using an effective diffusion coefficient, perhaps $D_\text{eff}=A_\text{rel}D$, where $A_\text{rel}$ is the relative area of the orifice.

For water vapor diffusing in air, $D\sim 2\cdot 10^{-5}$ to $3\cdot 10^{-5}$ (m$^2$/s), depending on the temperarute (you can find tables in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_diffusivity#Example_values), [Thermopedia](http://www.thermopedia.com/content/696/), and in the answers given to this [ResearchGate question](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Binary_diffusion_coefficients_for_water_vapour_in_air_at_normal_pressure), among others). You'd then need to solve the equation with the appropriate boundary conditions, which I haven't found online, but there are examples for simpler cases, e.g., for finding the [diffusion length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fick%27s_laws_of_diffusion#Example_solution_in_one_dimension:_diffusion_length) or in this [drug release application](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/materials-science-and-engineering/3-051j-materials-for-biomedical-applications-spring-2006/lecture-notes/lecture19.pdf).

### Mixing time scale estimate

As the orifice is small compared to the whole cube's area, and the diffusion coefficient $D$ also has a small numerical value, the equilibration time should be quite long. An estimate of how much might be possible from the Brownian escape probability from a box of side $L$ calculated by Gardiner Jr. in [*J. Phys. Chem.*, **1981**, 85 (5), pp 599–603](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/j150605a029), Eq. (19):

$$ P_\text{esc} \approx 1 - \left( 1 - \sqrt{\frac{4Dt}{\pi L^2}} \right)^3. $$

Taking $A_\text{rel} = A_\text{hole}/A = \pi r^2 /6$, where $A=6$ m$^2$ is the area of the full enclosure, and exchanging $D$ in the equation above by $D_\text{eff}\equiv A_\text{rel}D$, allows us to obtain the following expression for the time $t_\text{esc}$ it takes for a fraction $P_\text{esc}$ of the excess humidity to leave the box:

$$ t_\text{esc} = \frac{3L^2}{2r^2D} \left[ 1 - \left( 1- P_\text{esc} \right)^{1/3} \right]^2, $$

which gives a half life

$$ t_{1/2} \sim 3\cdot 10^6 \text{ s} \sim 40 \text{ days}. $$

If that is correct, in most situations the humidity levels **won't equilibrate in practice**.

A calculation in 1-D (accordingly using a 1-D version of Gardiner's result and $A=1\text{ m}^2$ in $A_\text{rel}$), yields a result of the same order of magnitude.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and its addendum, just now I was starting to solve the differential equation for an unidimensional system with initial condition  $ \phi(t=0,x)=30+50u(x) $, but the addendum made this calculus unnecessary. My conclusion is that it is not very important if the real box has small holes, because the  chemical desiccant will be enough to compensate the slow flow process.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui, An implicit assumption that I should have made explicit (corrected that now in the answer) is that the estimated time is for **diffusion only** mixing. That is, if there is, for example, convection between the boxes, mixing can take place much more quickly (though the desiccant should probably still be up to the job).